# How to share ARM Outputs between Stages in Azure Release Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azureportal

In Azure DevOps I have a Release Pipeline that has 2 Stages with the following Tasks:

Stage 1:

- ARM Template
- ARM Output

Stage 2:

- ARM Template

I want to pass ARM Outputs of the Stage 1, to the Stage 2, in order to use them in the ARM Template of the Stage 2.

Any ideas on how to achieve this in the Azure DevOs Portal?

**Pipeline:**
[image]

**Stage 1**

[image]

**Stage 2**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to write your ARM outputs to a variable group, and use that variable group in Stage 2.
I'm sure that will work, but I doubt that this is the best possible solution.

You can use the `Set-AzDevOpsArmOutputs` cmdlet from the [Arcus.Scripting](https://github.com/arcus-azure/arcus.scripting) scripting library.
You can see [here](https://scripting.arcus-azure.net/features/powershell/azure-devops/#setting-arm-outputs-to-azure-devops-variable-group) how you can use it.